# Will my Admob Unity Plugin be Obsolete?

Tags: unity, admob

When I got back to Google Admob Console I received this announcement:

"Beginning on 23 Jan 2018, Google Mobile Ads SDK versions older than 7.0.0 for Android and 7.0.0 for iOS will no longer be supported. Publishers with these older versions will not be able to serve ads in their apps(s). Please ensure that you have upgraded to the latest version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK."

I am concerned about whether the Unity game I released eight months ago will continue to serve Admob ads.

I think this pertains to many Unity developers. It seems that the Google Mobile Ads for Unity uses a different versioning system. Its current version is version v3.10.0.

So what is the latest version of Admob Unity Plugin that will be affected by this? Will we be affected at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes everyone using an older version than required will be effected with that announcement. The Unity package uses the native plugin in a wrapper and isn't different than the iOS and Android plugin at native level.

Go check here !

+Built and tested with:
 +- Google Play services 11.6.2
 +- Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK 7.27.0
 +- Unity Jar Resolver 1.2.59.0

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/commit/e393e68c9f6737f686af44aa1875e5e10a411464

They mention the underlying native plugin version with each release.

Comment: @Darco18s yes ! thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think my version is around 3.3. I wonder whether it will work.

Comment: no all ok !
+- Google Play services 10.2.0
 +- Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK 7.18.0

3.3 is fine !
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/commit/e8e9f8fc277f226ed099a8f20ead1dffa5740866